# PHP echo output

Tags: php

I'm just learning PHP, and I tried my first program which is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> <title>My first PHP</title> </head>
<body>

<?php
echo "<p>Hello world!</p>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But the output I got in my browser was

```
Hello world!
"; ?>
```

Why is "; ?> showing up on the browser?

Comment: is this your full code ? and what the extension of file?.html or .php?

Comment: is your file name with .php?

Comment: filename is first.php

Comment: Are you opening the file through a web-server?

Comment: @azemda  is this is your full code of the file?

Comment: How do you try to open your .php file? c:\path\to\file.php maybe?

Comment: It says he used his browser. `But the output I got in my browser was `

Comment: Is the full output from the browser just `Hello world! "; ?>`? or is it `<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>`

Comment: Your server is __not configured__ to process php-files. Over. Or you even __don't have__ a web server.

Comment: I opened it through http://localhost/first.php, I placed this file under /var/www/html and opened by localhost/first.php on search bar in the browser

Comment: check your `phpmyadmin` working or not also `localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Fedora 23, I placed this php file in /var/www/html which is the default root folder of web server.I didn't install php package, so I installed the php package and restarted the server and I got the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As **u_mulder** says in the comments, your webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc) isn't configured to process PHP files. The reason you're getting that output is because your browser is rendering the the below as a single opening HTML tag:

```
<?php
echo "<p>
```

and then displaying the subsequent characters:

```
Hello world!
"; ?>
```

as text. If you `View Source` in your browser, you'll see the full contents of your file.

To fix this, you'll need to enable PHP processing in your webserver's configuration - this will be different depending on which server software you are using, but you should be able to easily find a guide.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save your file in with .php extension.
2. code like this

   ```
         <?php 

       echo '<p> Hello world! </p> ' ; 
    ?>
   ```

their is nothing like that you show.. please check it. Always be sure your php syntax is correct.

Comment: I saved it as first.php

Comment: If you are learner .. You should read how to run php on your localhost. After this you will get your answer dear .